# Determining plane equivalency - coefficients

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I found a plane given a point and two contained parametric lines and got a correct answer...

 $14(x+2) + 7(z-1) = 0$ 

 However the solution, in addition to my answer, listed

"... equivalently  $2x+z+3=0$ "

Why are these planes equivalent? I see that you can expand this, simplify, and factor out a 3, but when I think about the component directions (e.g. $14x$ vs. $2x$) it doesn't make sense to me. 

Why are the coefficients able to be factored?

EDIT:

I understand that $\left\langle14,7\right\rangle$  is the same direction as $\left\langle 2,1 \right\rangle$, but if you were to graph the planes in my example you would see the following:
[link to image (not enough reputation points :/)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dph6c.jpg)

Please provide your reasoning, hopefully I'm not overthinking this :D

Comment: $\langle 14,7 \rangle$ is in the same direction as $\langle 2,1 \rangle$

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla You were right of course, I made a simple arithmetic error where I replaced 7z with z. Thank you for your comment